# Connecting to a continuous stream of data from URL in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am currently learning Android and have done fetching data from API endpoints that are static and are valid JSON objects.
I could do this using Retrofit and de-serialize it using GSON. But for a continuous stream of 'JSON Objects' (which are not formatted correctly in JSON), I am lost as to how I would open a connection and handle it.

This is a sample data stream. Do note that this pattern continues for quite a few hundred lines.

```
{
  "to": {
    "id": "A",
    "name": "George Washington"
  },
  "from": {
    "id": "B",
    "name": "Abe Lincoln"
  },
  "timestamp": "1234567",
  "alive": false
}
```

I looked into a more old-fashioned approach such as AsyncHttpClient, but again, I am not able to handle a continuous data stream since I can't even seem to connect to it properly.

```
                AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

                params.put("limit","5");
                params.put("page","0");

                client.get(url, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Headers headers, String response) {
                                Log.i(TAG,"Works!);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Headers headers, String errorResponse, Throwable t) {
                                Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(statusCode));
                            }
                        }
                );
```

So how would I go about connecting to such a URL?

Comment: I would not call a few hundred lines a continuous stream of json objects. A few hundred lines is nothing. Read them in all. After that convert to objects.

Comment: The URL endpoint is a continuous stream of JSON objects, that snippet was just to show what it contains (i had to omit the URL for obvious reasons). My problem isn't parsing, its how to actually connect to the URL.